# Android Text is wrapped in button - why?

Tags: android, layout

I have the following XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/verylongtext" android:layout_weight="1000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sometext" android:onClick="onClickButton" android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Though I have set a layout_weight there is still a linebreak in the text on the button, the button should show

sometext

but it shows

somet

ext

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify the orientation of your `LinearLayout`, so it is defaulting to horizontal.  The `TextView` is squeezing the `Button`.  Also, when you use `android:layout_weight`, then you often don't want to constrain the objects in the layout in the relevant dimension, so you can put "`0px`" instead of "`wrap_content`" or "`match_parent`" and let the weight determine the respective proportional sizes.

Comment: for the button it has to be wrap_content and for the button 0dp/px.

Answer (score 1):

Include `android:singleLine="true"` to **Button** xml.